# C++. Replacing an Array with another

Tags: c++, arrays

In subdivision curves, I want to update array with new one. But it doesn't working.

`vec2 Bezier[10] = {};` Taking initial points from mouse clicking in the screen. Then I am creating new array of points `vec2 umuminoqteler[1000] = {};`

and I want to replace Bezier with umuminoqteler, so in the next iteration I can use umuminoqteler as initial.
How can I solve it? `*Bezier=*umuminoqteler` doesnt work.

```
    {GLsizei winWidth = 800, winHeight = 600;
    float weights[4] = { -1.0 / 6, 4.0 / 6, 4.0 / 6, 1.0/6 };
    vec2 Bezier[10] = {};
    vec2 yeninoqteler[1000] = {};
    vec2 umuminoqteler[1000] = {};
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    for (int b = 0; b < tezelistsize; b++)
    {
        glVertex2f(umuminoqteler[b].x, umuminoqteler[b].y);
    }

    glEnd();
    *Bezier = *umuminoqteler;
    }


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQirB.png
```

Comment: Please post code as text in the question itself, instead of posting a screenshot. Format it as code with the `{}` button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Bezier` is an array of 10 elements and `umuminoqteler` is an array of 1000 elements. You can't resize `Bezier`. `Bezier` contains the address of the first element of the array. `*Bezier` is a reference to the first element of the array.

```
*Bezier = *umuminoqteler;
```

is similar to

```
Bezier[0] = umuminoqteler[0];
```

You could use a dynamic container like std::vector

```
{
    GLsizei winWidth = 800, winHeight = 600;
    float weights[4] = { -1.0 / 6, 4.0 / 6, 4.0 / 6, 1.0/6 };
    std::vector<vec2> Bezier(10);
    std::vector<vec2> yeninoqteler(1000);
    std::vector<vec2> umuminoqteler(1000);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    for (int b = 0; b < tezelistsize; b++)
    {
        glVertex2f(umuminoqteler[b].x, umuminoqteler[b].y);
    }

    glEnd();
    // Move 
    Bezier = std::move(umuminoqteler);
    // Or copy
    // Bezier = umuminoqteler;
}
```